# Spyder Editor - How to Disable Auto-Closing Brackets

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Does anyone know how to make Spyder stop automatically inserting closing brackets?

It often results in complete mess when you have multiple levels of different brackets. I had a look around and could only find posts about auto-closing quotes, but I'm not really interested in these. But those brackets are making me slightly miserable.

I had a look in *Preferences* but the closest I could find is *'Automatic code completion'*. But I certainly don't want all of it off especially when working with classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Spyder 4** and **Spyder 5** go to:

- *Tools* - *Preferences* - *Editor* - *Source code*

and **deselect** the following items:

- *Automatic insertion of parentheses, braces and brackets*
- *Automatic insertion of closing quotes* (since it's the same nuisance than with brackets)